# Не заполняется Map<String, String>

Tags: java

Метод не кладет в Map элементы, на выходе получаем NullPointerException, calculatedMap пуста. Подскажите у кого глаз наметан что не так в коде:

```
private Map<String, String> CalculateTime(String folderPath) {
    Map<String, String> startMap = ConvertFileToMap(folderPath + "/start.log");
    Map<String, String> endMap = ConvertFileToMap(folderPath + "/end.log");
    Map<String, String> calculatedMap = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> startEntry : startMap.entrySet()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> endEntry : endMap.entrySet()) {
            if (startEntry.getKey().equals(endEntry.getKey()))
                calculatedMap.put(startEntry.getKey(), TimeConverter.Calculate(endEntry.getValue(), startEntry.getValue()));
        }
    }
    return calculatedMap;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> calculatedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

---

> скажите, а вы понимаете смысл коллекции типа Map?

Я - да.

```
for (String key : startMap.keySet()) {
  if (endMap.containsKey(key)) {
    calculatedMap.put(key, TimeConverter.Calculate(endMap.get(key), startMap.get(key)));
  }
}
```

Comment: если не тяжело в двух словах почему так? вроде все логично на первый взгляд

Comment: @ДенисКороленко Перед вызовом методов `calculatedMap` этот объект надо создать. А Ваш код вызывает `put` от нулевой ссылки.

Comment: скажите, а вы понимаете смысл коллекции типа Map?

Comment: @ДенисКороленко, используйте [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) и не придется использовать проверки на существование. И почитайте про `Stream API`.